# How to fix this error ' this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key containerView.'?

Tags: swift

When the user what to sign up or login it has error and get this error in the output "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key containerView." 
this is the login code also signup has the same error and l'm sure it's a right codes.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet var Aemeil: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet var Apassword: UITextField!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  @IBAction func login (_ sender : Any){

      guard let email = Aemeil.text, let password = Apassword.text
        else {
            print("Form is not valid")
            return
      }

      Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email , password: password , completion: { (user,error) in
        if error == nil{
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AHome");
            self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil);
            print("Home page open")
        }
        else{
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }         

    })
  }
}
```

Comment: check in storyboard, if there is a `containerView` outlet exist then remove this., Or any outlet with warning sign remove this as well. You can check this in connection inspector.

Comment: All my connection inspector works right. there's another reason for this error?

Comment: Okay, is app crashing after the login, signup process or it is crashing on just coming to this view ?

Comment: I mean when you press login/ signup button ?

Comment: yes when i press login/signup it'll be crash

Comment: then the problem is in your next view controller's Interface builder file. Which will be open after login / signup. Check your Home view controller

Comment: there's no error in my home view controller and there class

Comment: If there is no error then why it is crashing. Can you share the project zip with me?

Comment: I removed the pages and do it again. know it's worked. thank you

Answer (score 5):

You have created a **binding** from a **storyboard element**, to an element in the corresponding **swift file**, with the name `containerView`. After that you have deleted the `containerView` variable in your **swift file**, but the binding still exists in the **storyboard**.

To solve this problem go to your **storyboard**, click on the `view controller`, like below:

[image: inspector2]

After that, click on the **connection inspector**, to see all bindings of your `viewcontroller` and delete the binding from the `containerView`:

[image: inspector1]

Comment: all my connection inspector works right , i don't need to remove thing. so what it's the problem?

Comment: For me this was the problem, thank you for the answer! It should be higher in this thread so more ppl actually read it.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar problem, I created a segmentview under which I've kept a containerView and removed the default segue that came along with that container view. After that I renamed the container view controller name and connected as `show` segue. This was the problem which caused me to face this issue. When I changed the show segue to `Embed` segue the problem resolved.